# Finding common ancestor in a binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

Following is a Python program I wrote to find the common ancestor in a binary tree (not BST) with no link to parent node. Please review.

```
def common_ancestor(N1, N2, head):
    if not head:
        return [None, 0, 0]

    left_status = common_ancestor(N1, N2, head.left)
    if left_status[0]:
        return left_status

    this_status = [None, 0, 0]
    if head == N1:
        this_status[1] = 1
    if head == N2:
        this_status[2] = 1

    right_status = common_ancestor(N1, N2, head.right)
    if right_status[0]:
        return right_status

    combined_status = [None, 0, 0]
    combined_status[1] = left_status[1] or this_status[1] or right_status[1]
    combined_status[2] = left_status[2] or this_status[2] or right_status[2]

    if combined_status[1] and combined_status[2]:
        print "Common Ancestor is %s" % head
        combined_status[0] = head

    return combined_status

if __name__ == "__main__":
    head = some_node
    print common_ancestor(5, 32, head)[0]
```

Comment: Your code gives the error `some_node is not defined`, posting the full code would make the job easier for reviewers, so that they can test it.

Comment: Sorry. It seemed like a duplicate. Felt it will not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. You didn't give us the definition of the node objects, so I'm guessing you used something like this:

   ```
   from collections import namedtuple
   Node = namedtuple('Node', 'left right'.split())
   ```
2. There's no docstring. How do I call `common_ancestor`? What is the meaning of the arguments `N1`, `N2`, and `head`? (I'm guessing that `N1` and `N2` are the nodes to find the nearest common ancestor of, and that `head` had to be the root node of the tree.)
3. The function `common_ancestor` does two things: it finds a node and prints a message about it. It would be better to separate these responsibilities.
4. The `print` statement means that the code is not portable to Python 3.
5. The function allocates a new list of three status elements *for each node* in the tree. But as we'll see below, we only need a *total* of two status elements.
6. The test `head == N2` is not quite right. Here we need the actual node `N2`, not just any node that happens to be equal to `N2`, so the test should use `is` rather than `==`.

#### 2. Simpler implementation

The function `common_ancestor` traverses the tree in depth-first order, keeping track of which of `N1` and `N2` have been visited so far. So let's start with a simple depth-first traversal implementation:

```
def traverse(node):
    """Visit all nodes in the tree starting at node, in depth order."""
    if node is None: return
    traverse(node.left)
    traverse(node.right)
```

Here's a binary tree with two shaded nodes that we want to find the common ancestor of. The thin line shows the order in which nodes are visited by a depth-first traversal.

[image: Depth-first traversal of a binary tree]

Suppose that we augment this traversal function so that it keeps track of how many of `n1` and `n2` have been visited so far:

```
count = 0
def traverse(node):
    """Visit all nodes in the tree starting at node, in depth order."""
    if node is None: return
    print("Entering {}, count={}".format(node, count))
    if node is n1: count += 1
    if node is n2: count += 1
    traverse(node.left)
    traverse(node.right)
    print("Exiting {}, count={}".format(node, count))
```

This figure shows the value of `count` on entry to each node:

[image: Number of target nodes visited on entry to each node]

And this figure shows the value of `count` on exit from each node:

[image: Number of target nodes visited on exit from each node]

You'll see that all the common ancestors of the two nodes have `count = 0` on entry and `count = 2` on exit (and only common ancestors have this property). So that means that we can implement `common_ancestor` like this:

```
def common_ancestor(n1, n2, head):
    """Return the nearest common ancestor of nodes n1 and n2 in the tree
    rooted at head.

    """
    count = 0   # How many nodes in {n1, n2} have been visited so far?
    ancestor = None

    def traverse(node):
        nonlocal count, ancestor
        if node is None or ancestor is not None: return
        count_at_entry = count
        if node is n1: count += 1
        if node is n2: count += 1
        traverse(node.left)
        traverse(node.right)
        if count_at_entry == 0 and count == 2 and ancestor is None:
            ancestor = node

    traverse(head)
    return ancestor
```

The `nonlocal` statement was new in Python 3, so if you're stuck on Python 2 then you'll have to find a workaround, for example using a status object:

```
class Status(object): pass
status = Status()
status.count = 0
status.ancestor = None
# etc.
```

#### 3. Efficient implementation?

The implementation discussed here has to traverse the whole tree and so takes time \$ O(n) \$. Whether this is important depends on how many common-ancestor queries you have. If there are many, then you'll probably want to change your tree data structure so that you can make efficient common-ancestor queries.

Adding parent pointers allows you to bring the query cost down to \$ O(\log n) \$ on balanced trees but if you have many common-ancester queries then you may prefer to preprocess the tree into a data structure that suppose \$O(1)\$ queries. See [Bender and Colton (2000)](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/261/BenFar-LCA-00.pdf) for an approach based on [range-minimum queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query).

Comment: `namedtuple` also accepts the field names separated with spaces or commas from a single string, there is no need to `split` it: `Node = namedtuple('Node', 'left right')`

Comment: @mkrieger1: Thanks, that's useful to know.

Comment: Hey thank you for the detailed review. However I feel the above code will break when either of the node to be found is absent and instead, two or more of the other node is present, since count doesn't differentiate between nodes.

Comment: On another note, how did you create those images? They look good!

Comment: (i) If "two or more of the other node" are found, then the data structure is not a tree. In a tree there is [exactly one path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) to each node from the root. (ii) I used [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Comment: @GarethRees Understood, I see you are comparing nodes, not values contained in the node.

Comment: @GarethRees I am confused, the `count` should increase as soon as we enter that node, since the predicate `node is n1` will be true immediately. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @CodeYogi: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @GarethRees, I am referring to the second figure.

Comment: @CodeYogi: Can you explain your problem in more detail? Which node are you talking about? Did you try running the `traverse` function on that tree? What value for `count` did it print on entering the node?

Comment: @GarethRees ok let me try once more. If we look at the left descendant in  the second figure where you say `This figure shows the value of count on entry to each node` but as far I see the count value should be equal to `1` before it calls the `traverse left and right again`. I already struggle with recursive solutions so, your explanation might open new door of possibilities for me to understand recursion or how to approach a solution via recursion. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeYogi: I think you have misunderstood what I meant by "on entry". I mean the value printed by the `print("Entering...")` line in the `traverse` function above the diagrams.

Comment: @GarethRees so, I am right in my interpretation. Just one more things what advice you would like to give to come up with a solution like these. Its sure that you have done a lot of practice but practiced the right way :)