# Time complexity of common ancestor algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree

I have an algorithm here to find the common ancestor of two nodes in a binary tree.

```
def commonAncestor(self, nodeA, nodeB, root):
            #checking if nodeB is a descendant of nodeA
            checkLeft = self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, root.leftChild)
            checkRight = self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, root.rightChild)
            if checkLeft == 1 and checkRight == 1:
                return root
            else:
                if checkLeft == 2:
                    # pdb.set_trace()
                    result = self.commonAncestor(nodeA, nodeB, root.leftChild)
                if checkRight == 2:
                    result = self.commonAncestor(nodeA, nodeB, root.rightChild)
                else:
                    raise ValueError("One of the values you have entered is not in the binary tree")

            return result

def checkSubtree(self, nodeA, nodeB, node):
            res = 0 #res is being initialized as a separate variable each time
            if node is None:
                return 0
            if node is nodeA or node is nodeB:
                res += 1
            res += self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, node.leftChild)
            res += self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, node.rightChild)
            return res
```

I think that the runtime of this algorithm is \$O(\log^2 n)\$. The first algorithm will run \$O(\log n)\$ times because it recurses through the binary tree, touching every node, and it subsequently calls the second function on each recursion which again recurses \$O(\log n)\$ times, correct?

I know this is a not an efficient algorithm, so how do I go about improving this? Specifically, I want to know how to approach the problem of thinking about how to improve this versus just seeing the code of the improved version.

Definition of node class

```
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right

    def insertLeftChild(self, val):
        self.leftChild = val

    def insertRightChild(self, val):
        self.rightChild = val

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild is not None

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild is not None
```

Comment: The runtime \$O(\lg^k n)\$ is not possible for this problem unless you guarantee that the tree is balanced. The degenerate case that the tree is a path shows that without constraints on the tree the problem is \$\Omega(n)\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime of the code in the post is \$Ω(n)\$, even if the tree is balanced, because `checkSubtree` has to visit all the nodes in the subtree.

In the worst case (where none of the nodes has a left child), the code is the post is \$O(n^2)\$ for the same reason.

So if you are going to visit all \$n\$ nodes, you might as well do this in just one pass over the tree, to make sure that you don't have quadratic behaviour in the worst case. See [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/84737/11728) for how to go about it.